# How to get the Displayed Webpage source

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-mobile, compact-framework

how can i get the web-page source displayed on a web-browser control, either in c# or Win32.even ATL COM also fine.
i mean.. i dont want to create new "HTTPReqest" or "openURL" to get source.. i want to get the source from the control only..is it possible for windows mobile..
if so how?.. please let me know.

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Assume this as the pseudocode

```
wbBrowser.Document.innerHtml
```

The `Document` property should be the starting point for you to look into.

Comment: Ya.. i tried to get through innerHTML, But its telling interface missing..
Just see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/bef6dc38-0dd9-4f97-8813-efbcc7b16414/?prof=required.. and at  "HRESULT hr = pItem->QueryInterface(/*__uuidof(IPIEHTMLElement)*/ IID_IPIEHTMLElement, (void **)&pElement );".. fails.. so any idea